# Why are scanf, getline, and gets all malfunctioning in my ASM program?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, nasm, glibc

I'm writing an x86 assembly project and I need to iterate over newline-delimited strings from stdout.

So I've tried this:

```
section .bss
    buffsize equ 255
    buff resb buffsize
    incount resd 1

section .text
    global _start
    extern getline
    extern stdin
    extern printf   
_start:
mov ebp, esp
push buff       ;getline expects a pointer to an array (a double pointer)
                ;so we need a spot to put the address of our buffer so we can push THAT address.
push stdin      ;stdin
push incount
push ebp
call getline

mov byte [buff + 254], 0

push buff
call printf
```

... but that gave me segfaults no matter what I did. So I tried this:

```
section .bss
    buffsize equ 255
    buff resb buffsize
    incount resd 1

section .text
    global _start
    extern fgets
    extern stdin
    extern printf

_start:
    push stdin
    push buffsize
    push buff
    call fgets  

    push buff
    call printf
```

... but that gave me segfaults too. So I tried this:

```
section .bss
    buffsize equ 255
    buff resb buffsize
    incount resd 1

section .data
    linescan db "%254[^\n]", 0x00
    lineheader db "%i       ", 0x00

section .text
    global _start
    extern scanf
    extern getchar
    extern stdin
    extern printf

_start:
    push buff
    push linescan
    call scanf
    call getchar    ;clean up the dangling newline

    push buff
    call printf
```

And it DIDN'T give me segfaults! (all of these printf-ed buff and had your regular "terminate cleanly" syscall after them by the way)

It doesn't work though. It accepts a line of input and then terminates silently... unless it's running in GDB, in which case it accepts more and then terminates silently, even though it definitely gets into `printf`.

So, uhh... what am I doing wrong? I need to accept arbitrary length input from stdin and the specification states I need to take it in 255 characters at a time. Processing the input line-by-line is part of the problem so I figured I'd just take it in one line at a time in the first place, but apparently that's a really hard thing to do.

Comment: You need to pop off the arguments after the function returned. For example, after your call to `getline` you need to `add esp, 12` to pop off the arguments.

Comment: @fuz Aww crap, I always forget that one. That shoudn't actually cause this though...

Comment: Before `mov ebp, esp` you must save `ebp` by `push ebp`. Before `ret` you must `pop ebp`. (and cleanup the stack as Fuz says).

Comment: Don't spam tags. This is not C.

Comment: Note that if your program starts with `_start` instead of `main`, you cannot use the C stdandard IO library as it requires some extra initialisation (as far as I know) that is typically done before `main`.

Comment: @fuz : Although not suggested practice (bad)technically you can because the `libc.so` file will have its initialization code run automatically when loaded into memory (assuming you aren't compiling as `-static`). Just so happens that code is enough for one to use IO properly. [_MUSL_ libc](https://www.musl-libc.org/)  is my preferred alternative in a case like this since it requires no startup code to be run.

Comment: In your first code you don't properly set up a pointer to a pointer and the parameters are wrong including the `push ebp` as the first parameter. The second code gets closer. But the primary issue is that `push stdin` is wrong. `stdin` is an external label with an address that stores a `FILE *`. You are pushing the address of a location that contains a FILE * (almost like you are doing FILE **). To get the value of `stdin` (which is a FILE *) you do `push dword [stdin]` . As well `printf` should take a first parameter as a pointer to format string (ie `"%s",0`).

Comment: As well since you avoided the normal _C_ startup and created your own `_start` label you will need to exit your program properly. You can do that by using `exit` from the _C_ library. ie. `call exit`

Comment: There is another hidden issue that you(by luck) won't see but it still an issue. With more modern versions of Linux you are required to keep the stack aligned on a 16 (or 32 byte boundary) prior to making any function call conforming to the [32-bit System V ABI](https://uclibc.org/docs/psABI-i386.pdf). By chance you'll likely get your program to work, but if you were to ever start working with floats and passing them into _C_ library functions you'd probably get an exception thrown.

Comment: After calling functions you should clean up the stack afterwards. If you push 3 4-byte values on the stack you should add 12 to _ESP_ after the call. 2 4-byte and you add 8 to _ESP_ after the call etc.

Comment: @Olaf I was figuring it might be me misusing the C library functions instead of an ASM-specific issue.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Thanks for all your advice! Turn your second comment into an answer so I can accept it. :P It's working now, although I had to use getline in "malloc what you need automatically" mode.

Comment: @Schilcote: Using library functions does not qualify a question for the C tag. The library is not required to be written in C (and in fact the library you link is **not** C, but machine code).